# trying to ping 192.168.2.2 from 192.168.1.1 pcs

Tags: switch, ip, network, mac-address, ping

im trying to ping pc2 from pc0 and it doesn't work
can anyone help tell me why?
pc0 is 192.168.1.1/24 and pc2 is 192.168.2.2/24.
The port connecting switch 0 is 192.168.1.100/24 and the port connecting switch 1 is 192.168.2.100/24.

[image]

Comment: What are the network masks used by the PCs?

Comment: @Zac67 both are /24

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`192.168.2.2/24` and `192.168.1.1/24` belong to different IP subnets. A router is required as gateway.

Whether or not both PCs belong to the same L2 segment = broadcast domain doesn't matter.

Comment: I added a router and connected it to the two switches, i tried the ping again and it didn't work.

Comment: Please add the router config to your question, using the editor's `{}` preformat option. Also, have you set a (default) gateway on the PCs?

Comment: Sorry I am still new to this and don't really get how to do it. when i added the default gateway to the pcs and tried the ping, i got destination host unreachable

Comment: i gave the two pcs on top the default gateway of 192.168.1.100 and the two pcs on the bottom the default gateway of 192.168.2.100

Comment: alright, so I found out that there was a typo in the configuration of the router IP port. it was 169 instead of 168. I changed it and it worked, sorry for wasting your time!